# Color scaling function

Tags: colors, interpolation

I am trying to visualize some values on a form. They range from 0 to 200 and I would like the ones around 0 be green and turn bright red as they go to 200.

Basically the function should return color based on the value inputted. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically, the general method for smooth transition between two values is the following function:

```
function transition(value, maximum, start_point, end_point):
    return start_point + (end_point - start_point)*value/maximum
```

That given, you define a function that does the transition for triplets (RGB, HSV etc).

```
function transition3(value, maximum, (s1, s2, s3), (e1, e2, e3)):
    r1= transition(value, maximum, s1, e1)
    r2= transition(value, maximum, s2, e2)
    r3= transition(value, maximum, s3, e3)
    return (r1, r2, r3)
```

Assuming you have RGB colours for the *s* and *e* triplets, you can use the transition3 function as-is. However, going through the HSV colour space produces more "natural" transitions. So, given the conversion functions (stolen shamelessly from the Python colorsys module and converted to pseudocode :):

```
function rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b):
    maxc= max(r, g, b)
    minc= min(r, g, b)
    v= maxc
    if minc == maxc then return (0, 0, v)
    diff= maxc - minc
    s= diff / maxc
    rc= (maxc - r) / diff
    gc= (maxc - g) / diff
    bc= (maxc - b) / diff
    if r == maxc then
        h= bc - gc
    else if g == maxc then
        h= 2.0 + rc - bc
    else
        h = 4.0 + gc - rc
    h = (h / 6.0) % 1.0 //comment: this calculates only the fractional part of h/6
    return (h, s, v)

function hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v):
    if s == 0.0 then return (v, v, v)
    i= int(floor(h*6.0)) //comment: floor() should drop the fractional part
    f= (h*6.0) - i
    p= v*(1.0 - s)
    q= v*(1.0 - s*f)
    t= v*(1.0 - s*(1.0 - f))
    if i mod 6 == 0 then return v, t, p
    if i == 1 then return q, v, p
    if i == 2 then return p, v, t
    if i == 3 then return p, q, v
    if i == 4 then return t, p, v
    if i == 5 then return v, p, q
    //comment: 0 <= i <= 6, so we never come here
```

, you can have code as following:

```
start_triplet= rgb_to_hsv(0, 255, 0) //comment: green converted to HSV
end_triplet= rgb_to_hsv(255, 0, 0) //comment: accordingly for red

maximum= 200

… //comment: value is defined somewhere here

rgb_triplet_to_display= hsv_to_rgb(transition3(value, maximum, start_triplet, end_triplet))
```

Comment: +1; I was going to ask a new question about how to improve a color algorithm i have for coloring a bar chart in HTML/PHP... SO suggested this question as similar and your answer helped me fix the issue without having to ask the question! Thanks!

Comment: +1, and a better name for your `transition` function would be `lerp` as that's mathematically what you're doing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_(computing)

Answer (score 7):

```
red = (float)val / 200 * 255;

green = (float)(200 - val) / 200 * 255;

blue = 0;

return red << 16 + green << 8 + blue;
```

Comment: This will make the midpoint (100) puke green: rgb(127, 127, 0). You would want your midpoint to be a bright yellow or orange. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168838/color-scaling-function#168980

Comment: I agree to this, that it will not look nice, however i am a coder and the midpoint was not part of the specification ;)

Answer (score 7):

You don't say in what environment you're doing this. If you can work with [HSV colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), this would be pretty easy to do by setting S = 100 and V = 100, and determining H by:

```
H = 0.4 * value + 120
```

[Converting from HSV to RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Conversion_from_HSV_to_RGB) is also reasonably easy.

[EDIT] Note: in contrast to some other proposed solutions, this will change color green -> yellow -> orange -> red.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a green that you like (RGB1 = #00FF00, e.g.) and a Red that you like (RGB2 = #FF0000, e.g.) and then calculate the color like this

```
R = R1 * (200-i)/200 + R2 * i/200
G = G1 * (200-i)/200 + G2 * i/200
B = B1 * (200-i)/200 + B2 * i/200
```

Answer (score 2):

For best controllable and accurate effect, you should use the HSV color space. With HSV, you can easily scale Hue, Saturation and/or Brightness seperate from each other. Then, you do the transformation to RGB.

Answer (score 2):

extending upon @tzot's code... you can also set up a mid-point in between the start and end points, which can be useful if you want a "transition color"!

```
//comment: s = start_triplet, m = mid_triplet, e = end_triplet
function transition3midpoint = (value, maximum, s, m, e):
    mid = maximum / 2
    if value < mid
      return transition3(value, mid, s, m)
    else
      return transition3(value - mid, mid, m, e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) I personally would pick a path through a color space, and map the values onto that path.

But that's a straight function.  I think you might be better suited to a javascript color chooser you can find with a quick color that will give you the Hex, and you can store the Hex.

Answer (score 1):

If you use linear ramps for Red and Green values as Peter Parker suggested, the color for value 100 will basically be [puke green](http://www.colourlovers.com/patterns/search?hex=7f7f00) (127, 127, 0). You ideally want it to be a bright orange or yellow at that midpoint. For that, you can use:

```
Red = max(value / 100, 1) * 255
Green = (1 - max(value / 100, 1)) * 255
Blue = 0
```