# What's the best way to create a relative color algorithm for data in an HTML table?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, conditional-formatting

I have an HTML table of data and I want to mimic [the Excel Color scales for conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428945(v=office.11).aspx) so it highlights the relative value across this set of data.

The HTML table is simply drawing out a list of rows and for each row I have a value ( 0 - 300) and i want to have it color the background of the row of the table based on this algorithm so I assume it will need to generate an HTML color name or value for each number that is input

Any help where to start here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340209/generate-colors-between-red-and-green-for-a-power-meter/340214#340214), and when deciding to generate the color, divide the row value/300 to use the exact function.

***Edit (Originally a comment)***

When specifying html colors, you can use the `rgb(Rvalue, Gvalue, Bvalue)` notation. Or you could convert the decimal values to their hex equivalent to to the #RRGGBB notation.

In javascript, this would be achieved by following [this method to convert to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript/57805#57805)

Comment: i dont understand.  how would i then convert this to HTML colors ??

Comment: how can you convert to the #RRGGBB notation ?

Comment: @ooo - once you have the hex values for the colors, you concatentate the results to produce a color `var col = '#' + rHex + ghex + bHex` and then jquery this fella to the correct table row