# Set the color of many divs from green to red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project there could be any amount of divs like a thousand, two thousand, a million etc.. I want their background colors to go from green to red. so they all get a different shade of color. the first div will be "real" green  the last div will be "real" red.

Here is what I have. As you can see there are divs at the end that get left without a background-color. I would prefer to solve this using rgb.

```js
$(function(){
  var r = 20;
  var g = 200;
  var b = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    $("body").append("<div class = 'box'>");
  }
  $(".box").each(function(){
    if(g > 0 && r < 255){
      $(this).css("background", "rgb("+ r + ","+ g + ","+ b + ")");
      g-=1;
      r+=1;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.box{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate colors between red and green for a power meter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340209/generate-colors-between-red-and-green-for-a-power-meter)

Comment: @steve I don't understand the top answer. if I do `R = (255 * n) / 100` and n == 1 I would get 2.55. I don't think I i could have the decimals as an RGB value. I tried it before.

Comment: @jackblank _"yea I don't mind if there is a little duplication. The main point is that at the beginning of the display users see green and further away they see things turning red."_ , _"it's a dynamic amount but It would probably less than 2000"_ Tried without `if` condition https://jsfiddle.net/0kL4f59z/ ?

Comment: but I meant the other guy. Kushner I think his name was. I liked his even though at a 1000 there was 5 divs with the same background. I prefer less duplicates.

Comment: @jackblank Not certain that approach returned expected results. Will undelete.

Comment: Monitors can only display ~17M colors.  That's *all* colors, not just those two (and those between).  If you have 1M divs, you are going to see many repeats.  Instead maybe you should consider multiple colors, or oscillating the colors back-and-forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone wrote this earlier but deleted it.

```js
$(function(){
  var r = 20;
  var g = 200;
  var b = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    $("body").append("<div class = 'box'>");
  }

  var noOfBoxes = $(".box").length,
      minRed = 20,
      maxRed = 255,
      maxGreen = 200

  $(".box").each(function(i){
    $(this).css("background", "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");

    g = parseInt(maxGreen - maxGreen * (i /noOfBoxes), 10)
    r = parseInt(minRed + maxRed * (i/ noOfBoxes), 10)
    console.log(g)
  })
})
```

```css
.box{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> yea I don't mind if there is a little duplication. The main point is
>   that at the beginning of the display users see green and further away
>   they see things turning red.

Try without `if` condition

```js
$(function(){
  var r = 20;
  var g = 200;
  var b = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    $("body").append("<div class = 'box'>");
  }
  $(".box").each(function(){
      $(this).css("background", "rgb("+ r + ","+ g + ","+ b + ")");
      g-= 1;
      r+= 1;
  })
})
```

```css
.box{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @jackblank With `r` beginning at `0`, `g` beginning at `255` https://jsfiddle.net/0kL4f59z/1/

Comment: I never knew that you could set a an RGB value to a negative. you are doing that to the green value. what happens when it gets below 0. it just goes to black? G would be like 0?

Comment: @jackblank There are not any negative values. Once value reaches `0` value does not decrement to a negative value. There could be another approach, trying now

Comment: I like the other guys answer I just noticed that with this if I do a thousand divs there will be  765 divs at the end with the background of `rgb(255, 0, 10)` too many duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, do not Increment and decrements the value of `r` and `g` at the same time, do it alternatively...

```js
$(function(){
  var r = 55
  var g = 200;
  var b = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    $("body").append("<div class = 'box'>");
  }
  $(".box").each(function(i){
    if(g > 0 && r < 255){
       $(this).css("background", "rgb("+ r + ","+ g + ","+ b + ")");
       if(i%2 == 0)
       {
         g-=1;
       }
       else
       {
         r+=1;
       }
      
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.box{
  border:2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach utilizing `css` `linear-gradient` at `background` of container element holding `.box` elements, `transparent` `background` at `.box` elements; included `outline` , `border` to mask `linear-gradient` visibility at outside right of container; note this portion of `css` could still be improved. Set `for` loop to `2000` iterations. `linear-gradient` should display expected color transitions gradually from `lime` to `red` between `0` to `n` `.box` elements.

```js
for (var i = 0, container = document.getElementById("container"); i < 2000; i++) {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class=box></div>");
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#container {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lime, red);
  outline:25px solid #fff;
  border:25px solid #fff;
  width: calc(100vw - 2.5%); /* adjusted for width of stacksnippets */
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 20px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0kL4f59z/5/