# Have different Linear progress bar's indicator color with different level

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm stuck with this one implementation of material **LinearProgressIndicator** but have no idea on how I can make it functional in that way.

My naive approach is to have different color at different percentage level such as for "10%-Red, 25%-Yellow, 35%-Orange, 50%+ Green". So, I just wanted to know if there exist any other way for gradient color which starts from red and goes all above upto green.

**Updated Question with picture**
[image: Attached the exact description]

Something like this picture!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/340209 ?

Comment: No, that's not the expected output! I'll update my question with expected outcome.

Comment: I have attached an example picture which suggests what I actually wanted to implemented!

Comment: So you're asking how to draw lines of four different colours?  Or how to calculate a colour, based on a percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions can be to generate a color from the progress and update it to the progress bar.

```
 private fun updateProgress(progress: Int) {
    val color = when (progress) {
        in 0..10 -> Color.RED
        in 11..34 -> Color.YELLOW
        in 35..54 -> Color.MAGENTA
        else -> Color.GREEN
    }
    updateProgressBar(progress, color)
}

private fun updateProgressBar(progress: Int, color: Int) {
    binding.progressBar.apply {
        setProgress(progress)
        setIndicatorColor(color)
    }
}
```