# Function that takes two hexidecimal colors and returns an array of all colors "between" them?

Tags: javascript, colors

Something like this:

```
function transitionArray(colorA,colorB) {
  var transArray = [];
  var lastInSequence = // determine this somehow?
  var currentColor = null;
  while (currentColor != lastInSequence) {
    // convert hexidecimal to decimal?
    // increment in some manner?
    // push to transArray?
  };
  return transArray;
};
```

edit: By "between" I mean the route between them on a color wheel... or really any gradual-looking transition.

Comment: Define "colors between".

Comment: Are you doing this to try to animate colors?

Comment: eggborne.com/tiles - I want the colors to cycle smoothly here instead of randomly.

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292649/javascript-color-animation) sounds like it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps useful in creating a solution [How to figure out all colors in a gradient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732401/how-to-figure-out-all-colors-in-a-gradient/8732626#8732626).